# Spring EnableAuthorizationServer with custom AuthenticationManager

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0, javabeans

I am setting up an OAuth2 + OpenID connect server using Spring security. I have been trying to use the automatic **/oauth/token** & **/oauth/authorize** endpoints that are defined when you use the @EnableAuthorizationServer annotation on a class.

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter{
```

In the same class, I have autowired an AuthenticationManager to use in configuring the AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer. I have debugged & confirmed that the correct bean is being autowired.

```
    @Autowired
  private AuthenticationManager authMan;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints)
            throws Exception{
        endpoints
        .tokenStore(tokenStore())
        .userApprovalHandler(userApprovalHandler())
        .authenticationManager(authMan);
}
```

The problem is, there are two WebSecurityConfigurers being created, the one I defined and what appears to be the default WebSecurityConfigurer. Here is part of the one I defined:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsSrvc detailsSrvc;

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

       @Bean
        public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
            DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider
              = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
            authProvider.setUserDetailsService(detailsSrvc);
            authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
            return authProvider;
        }

       @Autowired
        protected void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
          auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
        }

       @Override
       @Bean(name="myAuthenticationManager")
       public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
           return authenticationManager();
}
```

Unfortunately, the default is being called when I navigate to localhost:8080/outh/token with my browser. I can tell because my custom UserDetailsService is not being used during the authentication, and because I put a breakpoint on the getWebSecurityConfigurers method in org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.AutowiredWebSecurityConfigurersIgnoreParents:

```
    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
    public List<SecurityConfigurer<Filter, WebSecurity>> getWebSecurityConfigurers() {
        List<SecurityConfigurer<Filter, WebSecurity>> webSecurityConfigurers = new ArrayList<SecurityConfigurer<Filter, WebSecurity>>();
        Map<String, WebSecurityConfigurer> beansOfType = beanFactory
                .getBeansOfType(WebSecurityConfigurer.class);
        for (Entry<String, WebSecurityConfigurer> entry : beansOfType.entrySet()) {
            webSecurityConfigurers.add(entry.getValue());
        }
        return webSecurityConfigurers;
}
```

The beansOfType map has two entries, but only if I have a class with the @EnableAuthorizationServer annotation. (Only 1 if I comment out annotation)

How do I get my AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter (or whatever is actually processing the requests to /oauth/token) to use the WebSecurityConfigurer defined in my WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter? I believe I can get around this issue by defining my own endpoints, and maybe that's the only solution, but I was hoping to utilize the default endpoints.